# Vim command to replace part of matched string

Tags: vim

Relatively new to vim search/replace commands and wondering how to replace part of matched string via vim commands.

E.g. If I have

```
printf(_UNICODE("Text and %d I want to preserve."), 20);
```

and I wish to get rid of the Unicode conversion and make it become

```
printf("Text and %d I want to preserve.", 20);
```

which means getting rid of the `_UNICODE(` and the `)` but preserving the format string in between.

Can someone please help me come up with a vim command to do that and possibly explain?

Thanks a ton in advance! :)

Comment: Try this sequence `/_UNICODE⏎2wdi(2bvt,p`

Comment: This one is better `/_UNICODE⏎f"di(2bvt,p` Handles the case if the format string starts with `(`

Comment: @balki Is there a way to apply these to all the occurrences in a file like %s....?

Comment: You can record in a macro and run it multiple times. But not like with `%s`

Comment: @balki Thanks for your response. I'd prefer an `%s` solution but I upvoted yours too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
:s/_UNICODE(\([^)]*\))/\1/g
```

or

```
:%s/_UNICODE(\([^)]*\))/\1/g
```

Match "_UNICODE(" + not-a-closing-bracket + ")" and replace with just the not-a-closing-bracket part.

(%s to do all lines instead of current line)

Comment: This will break if the text in the format string contains a `)`

Comment: Is \1 a register here? When I typed it in it replaced the not-a-closing-bracket part with "\1"... am I missing something here?

Comment: @user3291342: The \1 should refer to the part of the regular expression between the first (in this case, only) \( and \) bits. I tested in MacVim and an HPUX vi and it works for me. Are you sure you copied the string exactly?

Comment: @balki: That's a fair criticism. I am assuming a relatively known/simple use case. It could be modified to treat ") as the delimiter or made even more complicated to handle potential escaping of the " and ).

Comment: @EdmCoff That did not work on my editor vim plugin but worked in actual vim. Sorry for the confusion.